# Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

#### Background

In order to implement async commands in an MVVM app I went through the following tutorials by Stephen Cleary.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn605875 Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands

#### Problem

When reimplementing what he proposed step by step I stumbled upon the problem that the `PropertyChanged` event handler in the command is always `null`. When running Steves sample code it is not `null`.

In order to understand this better I started from scratch with implementing the most basic command that one could think of:

```
public class SimpleCommand : ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // having a break point on the following line
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Note that I have a break point set on the line that throws the `NotImplementedException` because I just want to see whether `PropertyChanged` is `null` or not.

The viewmodel basically just creates this command and the view binds to it via a button.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand SimpleAction { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SimpleAction = new SimpleCommand();
    }

    ...
}
```

The window just contains one button to call that command

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainViewModel></viewModels:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding SimpleAction}"
            Content="Click Me!"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My assumption is that when a command implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then the framework listens onto the `PropertyChanged` event which is obviously wrong.

So how does it work in Steves examples then? There he just implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `NotifyTaskCompletion` or `AsyncCommand` and `PropertyChanged` is not `null`.

Looking at other SO posts the usual answer in general is that `DataContext` is not set. Still I don't see how to set this for a command.

#### Actual Question

How to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly on a command (based on `ICommand`) in MVVM (C#)?

Comment: The actual question you should ask first: what property changes should WPF listen to? There is no need for a listener as long as no property inside the command is bound to the view.

Comment: That's right, your command doesn't provide any properties to the view to use. The example that you referenced is invoking `Process complete` in the UI so there is going to be a listener attached to it. Just like there is one for your `ViewModel` if you want to use it you will need to replicate the example correctly.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do I see the `NotifyTaskCompletion` used in that tutorial...

Comment: The UI only listens to CanExecuteChanged on an ICommand. I don't see "Steve's sample" so I don't know what he's doing with it.

Comment: @grek40 & XAMIMAX, you are right. That's exactly the problem. It only works if there is also at least one binding to a property within the command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command itself has no subscribers unless you bind to a property of the command itself.

That's what @Stephen Cleary does in his article. He binds to the `Execution` property of the `AsyncCommand<TResult>` class. You bind to the `SimpleAction` property of the `MainViewModel` class.

So in your sample code, the `SimpleCommand` object has no subscribers and that's why the event handler returns a `null` reference.

Comment: No I got it. That's it. So it is not enough to have a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There needs to be at least one binding to that class so that the framework listens to `PropertyChanged`. Thanks.